# Getting data in Backtrader issue

Tags: python, backtrader

I am trying to write a backtesting strategy on Backtrader in Python, and below is the code that is giving me the error. I am using the latest version of backtrader as of July 2, 2021.

```
import backtrader as bt
import backtrader.feeds as btfeeds
from datetime import datetime

cerebro = bt.Cerebro()
cerebro.broker.setcash(100000)
data = btfeeds.YahooFinanceData(dataname="SPY", fromdate=datetime(2016, 6, 25), 
todate=datetime(2021, 6, 25))
cerebro.adddata(data)
cerebro.run()
```

The error that I am getting is

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\Users\risha\PycharmProjects\PythonDataScience\BacktraderBacktesting\TestingData.py",
> line 9, in 
> cerebro.run()   File "C:\Users\risha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\backtrader\cerebro.py",
> line 1127, in run
> runstrat = self.runstrategies(iterstrat)   File "C:\Users\risha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\backtrader\cerebro.py",
> line 1210, in runstrategies
> data._start()   File "C:\Users\risha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\backtrader\feed.py", line
> 203, in _start
> self.start()   File "C:\Users\risha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\backtrader\feeds\yahoo.py",
> line 355, in start
> super(YahooFinanceData, self).start()   File "C:\Users\risha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\backtrader\feeds\yahoo.py",
> line 94, in start
> super(YahooFinanceCSVData, self).start()   File "C:\Users\risha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\backtrader\feed.py", line
> 674, in start
> self.f = io.open(self.p.dataname, 'r') FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'SPY'

I am confused on why this is happening. I have tried running this by adding a strategy in Cebro as well, but that still caused the same error. Could someone please help me fix this issue?

Comment: Just a clarifying comment: This error was just fixed on Backtrader2. See pull request: https://github.com/backtrader2/backtrader/pull/67 for the fix. You can install backtrader two, or just add the one line found here: https://github.com/backtrader2/backtrader/pull/67/files in to your backtrader library in feeds/yahoo.py

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I actually figured out the solution. If you use, the code:

```py
import yfinance as yf

data = bt.feeds.PandasData(dataname=yf.download('SPY', '2015-07-06', '2021-07-01', auto_adjust=True))
```

This will allow you to get the data from online for any ticker. You will also have to use:

```
pip install yfinance
```

before you run this code.

Comment: I got this error ```'RRuleLocator' object has no attribute 'set_view_interval'``` using this approach, do you know the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Yahoo! Finance has changed slightly their structure. **Now requires headers** for the data retreival on the http request. Since backtrader has a "old version" of *yahoo.py* on line 271 you need to add the headers. Once done works fine.

It happens as well with pandas & pandas-datareader which you'll need to upgrade them if you use it. (Which has been already sorted)

For Backtrader in yahoo.py line 271:

```
 crumb = None
 sess = requests.Session()
 ## ADD HEADERS
 sess.headers['User-Agent'] = 'backtrader'
 ## END HERE
 for i in range(self.p.retries + 1):  # at least once
     resp = sess.get(url, **sesskwargs)
     if resp.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
```

Here you have the original link for the yahoo.py [changes](https://github.com/backtrader2/backtrader/pull/67/commits/f562d71412980b6a6377cc45482d5054528792a5).

Probably backtrader will launch a upgrade soon.

For Pandas and Pandas-DataReader

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
pip install --upgrade pandas-datareader
```

Have a nice day ;).

Answer (score -1):

try to upgrade your backtrader. On 3rd of July there is a new release. I did update it but it still does not work.
The problem is that it does not bt.feed.YahooFinance, take the data in the correct format. It is a new bug... I am waiting for them to fix it as well.

Comment: I fixed mine manually. So in the dataname=.... download and upload manually the file instead of 'SPY'

Comment: This may be better included as a comment rather than an answer.